# Files downloaded in electron with node's request library are corrupted

Tags: node.js, electron

I am trying to download png and word files on a webserver using node's request library in electron. The files generate by the code are corrupted. Below is the code

```
 var req =new request({
    method: 'GET',
    uri: file_url,
     headers:{
       "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
       "Content-disposition": "attachment"
     }
}).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.resolve()+"\\test.png",{defaultEncoding: 'binary'}));
```

I tried with and without headers and encoding options. But the result is still the same. Is there any other way